Whats the derivation of a low speed ratio for stall warning?
I've seen an equation related to stall and angle of attack in a few places like this patent that goes more or less:
$$ \frac{CAS_{alert}}{CAS_{current}}  = \sqrt{\frac{C_{L,current}}{C_{L,alert}}} $$
Where CAS is your airspeed and C_l is the coefficient of lift at certain angle of attack.
It seems intuitive, for example if you are in unaccelerated flight and using 90% of your available lift then you are about 5% over your alert speed. However I'm confused about a few details like why there's a square root in the equation, or whether there are scenarios where this is just an approximation and it breaks down. Where does this speed ratio come from?

Not sure the complete context of your question but much information can be found at https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-C/part-25/subpart-B/subject-group-ECFR1cd58fc7d4bfee0/section-25.207 for part 25 certified aircraft.
With regards to your equation, it does correctly reflect the proportionality between CL and airspeed for 1-g level flight with the caveat that technically, it's for Vtrue, not Vcas.
{CL = W/(rhoVtVt*Sref/2)}

$\rho$ times $\text{TAS}^2$ is approximately $\text{CAS}^2$. (More accurately it's equivalent airspeed squared).

Ve = Vt * sqrt(sigma) = Vt * sqrt(rho/rhoSL)

It's a simple scaling law. The lift is proportional to $C_L$ times the square of the equivalent airspeed. In other words, for a given load factor, $C_L(\text{EAS})^2$ is a constant. So $\frac{\text{EAS}_1}{\text{EAS}_2}=\sqrt{\frac{C_{L,2}}{C_{L,1}}}$ is true for any two flight conditions at the same load factor.
At lower mach numbers equivalent and calibrated airspeeds are the same so they are often used interchangeably.
